# Race Condition emulation crashes in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, race-condition

I'm trying to emulate a race-condition in C++. Below is my code and I'm using xcode as my IDE

the relevant code goes like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
int value=0;
int* ptr = &value;

racer r1(ptr, "John");
racer r2(ptr, "Mike");

std::thread my_thread1(r1);
std::thread my_thread2(r2);

//guard g1(my_thread1);
//guard g2(my_thread2);

my_thread1.join();
my_thread2.join();

cout<<"result:= "<<*ptr<<endl;
cout <<"end!"<<endl;
return 0;
```

}

and for the racer I have:

```
racer::racer(int* r, char const* name)
{
    this->r=r;
    this->name=name;
}

void racer::print_result()
{
     cout<<this->name<<" "<<*r<<endl;
}

void racer::count_now()
{ 
    for ( int i = 0; i < 50; i++ )
    {
       *r = *r + 1;
       cout<<this->name<<". "<<*r<<endl;
    }
 }


void racer::operator()()
{
     count_now();
}
```

So basically, my expected result without the race is *ptr = 100 because there are 2 threads that runs together on the same resource. So sometimes when I run it I get 100 and sometimes it crashes and I get the error message below. Why is that? In other words, why can't I get a value that is >100? when it crashes does it mean that I have a race condition and hence the error?

[image]

Comment: the code works fine on on my linux.

Comment: @Leon Li did you get result>100?

Answer (score 1):

First for the simple question: Since you use Xcode I'm assuming you use an x86-based processor. My understanding is that you won't be able to produce a simple data race the way you are trying to do it because the x86-based Intel processors implement a strong cache coherency protocol, more precisely the [MESI protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol). On different system with weaker cache coherency protocols, e.g., on ARM-based processors I think you'd get funny values but currently I can't try it out.

The harder question is: Why does it crash? The debugger clearly shows a crash in the IOStreams library which seems to result from concurrent access to `std::cout`. However, at the line pointed to by the debugger, I can't really see where a null pointer dereference would come from. The only pointer dereferenced is is `this` (the function `std::basic_streambuf<...>::overflow()` is a `virtual` function, i.e., access to the virtual function table is needed).

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code is unlikely to produce race conditions. The precondition of a race condition is the context switch among threads. Your example is too simple

```
1) only two threads.
2) Each thread, on linux, by default, gets about 50ms CPU time for each context switch.
```

Your code only has 50 (increments + cout).  This 50 loops can be easily completed in 50ms, and thus both threads will complete without any context switch while executing.  Without (enough) context switch, you won't witness any race condtion.

To improve your chances:

```
1) start 50 threads.
2) each thread execute 50 loops.
3) each loop does 10 increments.
```

Or increase the numbers in 1) 2) 3) until you start seeing many context switches and hopefully lead to race conditions. A precursor will be that the output messages are mixed of ("John", "Mike" ...)